# Height and width of the components from Zeplin to the Website

Tags: css, sass, responsive-design, zeplin

When I apply the values such as height and width of the components from Zeplin to the Website, it is quite different. I guess should I not follow these rules?

I investigated related to the question, but not find info. Can you help me with how to use (any article or video etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Height, width or sometimes button are not be same according to web side. I recommend you to use it visually.